# Delphi mysql datetime plus minutes subtract current time

Tags: mysql, delphi

I am trying to create a countdown timer. I have `created_at` value, `life_time` value and `current_time`.

I want to sum `created_at` and `life_time` and subtract `current_time`.

> created_at : 2017-05-22 04:49:54
>
> life_time : 500 (minutes)

and i can find current time like [this](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Now). (12/10/2002 13:37:25)

But all variables have different format. How can i

```
created_at + life_time - current_time = I WANT (dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss)
```

`created_at` defined as a datetime and lifetime defined as an integer and minutes in mysql.

Comment: What if the server time will be different from time on the client machine? Also, why did you define data type for number of minutes as `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @Victoria i thought difference from time between server and client machine, but i could not find any other solution. So I thought i could set the client timezone accordingly because i know the timezone on the server. Do you have any better idea about this problem ? I'm trying to show the remaining time to expiration date to the user. (and yes i wrote wrong, minutes as Integer (edited))...

Comment: I would simply get from the server remaining time (in minutes, even though it won't be accurate).

Comment: @Victoria you are right. You are helping me with all my questions, and also thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add time unit to mysql use Date_add function like this :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-12-28", INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
```

This link gives good example for that

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

time can be given in negative also which will help you to create a count down